# Get seconds value and display to console window

Tags: java, javafx

I have coded a simple countdown timer in JavaFX and implements the Timer with binding so whenever the value of timeSeconds changes, the timerLabel text also changes.

How to get the value of current seconds and show it to console window?
the output should display the value of current seconds every new line like:
5
4
3
2
1
0

```
public class FXTimerBinding extends Application
{
//  private class constant and somme variables
private static final Integer STARTTIME = 5;
private Timeline timeline;
private Label timerLabel = new Label();
private IntegerProperty timeSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(STARTTIME);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    //  setup the Stage and the Scene(the scene graph)
    primaryStage.setTitle("FX Timer binding");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    //  configure the label
    timerLabel.setText(timeSeconds.toString());
    timerLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    timerLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 4em;");

    // Bind the timerLabel text property to the timeSeconds property
    timerLabel.textProperty().bind(timeSeconds.asString());

    //  create and configure the Button
    Button button = new Button("Start timer");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(timeline != null)
                timeline.stop();

            timeSeconds.set(STARTTIME);
            timeline = new Timeline();

            KeyValue keyValue = new KeyValue(timeSeconds, 0);
            KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(STARTTIME + 1), keyValue);

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
            timeline.playFromStart();

     System.out.println("get every seconds value and display to console window");
        }
    });
```

from: http://www.asgteach.com/blog/?p=334

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: tried the other that doesn't implement the binding

Comment: Does `value of current seconds` represent the second value of the current time?

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Your code works fine for me: the label counts down. Are you wanting some other behavior when `timeSeconds` changes?

Comment: get and display in console window the value of timeSeconds whenever it updates.

Comment: It is already displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform some other action when the actual value of `timeSeconds` changes, just add a listener to it:

```
timeSeconds.addListener((observable, oldTimeValue, newTimeValue) -> {
    // code to execute here...
    // e.g.
    System.out.println("Time left: "+newTimeValue);
});
```

If you are changing the UI in response to the countdown changing value, though, a binding of the kind of already have is preferable, imho.

Comment: great it works! now i was able to reset the timer back into seconds 5,